# No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have Python version 3.7.8 (64-bit) and pip version pip-20.3.3. I am trying to install tensorflow 2.1.3 but it is giving me this error.:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.1.3
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.1.3

Comment: As far as I can tell, there has never been a 2.1.3 version of Tensorflow. Why are you trying to install 2.1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Tenserflow's release history](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history), there really is no version 2.1.3. [2.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.2/) is the latest 2.1.x version that's available, or you could hop to a newer minor version, such as 2.2.0, or the latest 2.4.0.